# ACF scheduled repeater fields

Tags: advanced-custom-fields

1. Is there a way to schedule repeater fields to appear on the front end at start date & time and be taken down at end date & time?
2. Is there a way to have those repeater fields deleted from the admin at end date & time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Yes.

You could keep other fields to specify the timestamp of the start and end dates. You then compare the timestamp on the front-end. If the current timestamp is larger than the start date and smaller than the end date, display the fields.

2. Yes, kinda.

I don't know if there's a straightforward way to do it, but you can probably write a function to check the repeater fields from the `postmeta` table and delete them using [delete_post_meta](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/delete_post_meta).